# I want to use currency formatter to set amount with commas and decimal with limit also character should not exceed by 10 and $ should appear first

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use currency formatter to set amount with commas and decimal with limit also character should not exceed by 10 and $ should appear first .
Code sample is below but not working with decimal.

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        var newLength = 10
        if textField == donateAmountTextfield {
                let text = donateAmountTextfield.text!
                newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
        }
    return newLength <= 10 // Bool
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == donateAmountTextfield {
        if donateAmountTextfield.text != "" {
            dollerSign.isHidden = true
            if let amountString = donateAmountTextfield.text?.currencyInputFormatting() {
                donateAmountTextfield.text = amountString
            }
    } else {
            dollerSign.isHidden = false
        }
    } else if textField == enterCardNumber {
        if validateData.validateDonation((donateAmountTextfield?.text)! as String) {
            self.view.makeToast("Please enter valid Donation amount", duration: 5.0, position: CSToastPositionCenter)
        }
    }

}
```

class for formatter-

```
extension String {

    // formatting text for currency textField
    func currencyInputFormatting() -> String {

        var number: NSNumber!
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currencyAccounting
        formatter.currencySymbol = "$"
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

        var amountWithPrefix = self

        // remove from String: "$", ".", ","
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[^0-9]", options: .caseInsensitive)
        amountWithPrefix = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: amountWithPrefix, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count), withTemplate: "")

        let double = (amountWithPrefix as NSString).doubleValue
        number = NSNumber(value: (double / 1))

        // if first number is 0 or all numbers were deleted
        guard number != 0 as NSNumber else {
            return ""
        }

        return formatter.string(from: number)!
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmeasurement have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
IBtextFieldName.text = self.formatCurrency(strAmount: strAmount) //In viewDidLoad

func formatCurrency(strAmount strAmount: String) -> String  {

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
    let numberFromField = (NSString(string: strAmount).doubleValue)/100
    return formatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)!
}

//For character should not exceed by 10

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let newCharLength = textField.text!.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length

    if newCharLength >= 10 {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: what is strAmount amount in viewdidload

Comment: formatter.string(from: NSNumber(numberFromField)) is also thrwoing error .